# Work with Excel in 64 bit Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, c#-4.0, iis

I want to open an Excel file and update specific cells in specific sheet.For example update cell `A1` in `Book1` and update `B3` in `Book2` and ...

What is prefered way to do this in 64 bit windows?

Currently I do this with `OWC11` and change `IIS 7` and set `Enable 32-bit Applications` to `true`.And It works Fine. For some reason I can't set `Enable 32-bit Applications` to `true` and when change it to `False` my program does not work

thanks

Comment: I'm assuming this is 32-bit Office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Office Interop is NOT supported in sever-scenarios (like using Excel from ASP.NET/IIS) by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).**

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop/installing Excel on the server:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write all MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can install 64bit version of Excel and use 64bit versions of the COM libraries. Just remember that you can reference just one of them (either 32bit or 64bit) at a time unless you want to do some extra magic in your code like dynamically loading references.